# How to call an async function in poll() method?

Tags: rust, future

I want to call async function in Future::poll(), but the poll() is not async function, so I have to poll the async fn, but got error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `poll` found for opaque type `impl Future` in the current scope
  --> src\lib.rs:18:22
   |
18 |         let a = fut1.poll(cx);
   |                      ^^^^ method not found in `impl Future`
```

I try to Pin::new(async fn()).poll(), got another error:

```
error[E0277]: `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src\lib.rs:33:23: 36:2 {ResumeTy, u64, Duration, impl Future, ()}]>` cannot be unpinned
  --> src\lib.rs:22:23
   |
22 |         let pinfut1 = Pin::new(&mut fut1);
   |                       ^^^^^^^^ within `impl Future`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src\lib.rs:33:23: 36:2 {ResumeTy, u64, Duration, impl Future, ()}]>`
...
33 | async fn fn1() -> i32 {
   |                   --- within this `impl Future`
```

code:

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::{Arc,Mutex};

#[pin_project::pin_project]
struct Person<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    age: i32,
}

impl<'a> Future for Person<'a> {
    type Output = i32;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let mut this = self.project();
        *this.age += 1;

        // error: poll() ^^^^ method not found in `impl Future`
        // let mut fut1 = fn1();
        // let a = fut1.poll(cx);

        // error: Pin::new() ^^^^^^^^ within `impl Future`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator::GenFuture
        let mut fut1 = fn1();
        let pinfut1 = Pin::new(&mut fut1);
        let a = pinfut1.poll(cx);

        if *this.age > 4 {
            Poll::Ready(*this.age)
        } else {
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}

async fn fn1() -> i32 {
    async_std::task::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
    123
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Person {name: "jack", age: Default::default()};
    async_std::task::block_on(async {
        let a = p1.await;
        dbg!(a);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To call `poll` on `fut1` which is returned by `fn1`, you need to obtain a `Pin<&mut F>`, where `F` is the type of the future `fut1`. There are at least three possibilities to do this (I omit `unsafe`):

1. If `fut1` implements `Unpin`, you can call `Pin::new`,
2. you can pin `fut1` on the heap by using `Box::pin`, or
3. you can pin `fut1` on the stack by using the `futures_util::pin_mut!` macro.

It is sometimes a little bit hard to figure out whether `Unpin` is implemented, and if not, then why. A general advice here is to desugar the signature of `fn1` into: `fn fn1() -> impl Future<Output = usize> + Unpin`. The compiler errors are usually more precise then.

The implementation of the `pin_mut!` macro has some useful insights, btw. It uses the Rust type system to move the future and shadows the variable, s.t. it cannot be accessed anymore, and by doing this, it guarantees that the invariants of `Pin::new_unchecked` are satisfied and therefore it can call it.

Comment: When I change my async fn1() to:
fn fn1() -> impl Future<Output=i32> + Unpin,  got error: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ within `impl Future`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:29:11: 34:6]>`

Comment: @Anunaki: Yes, this is also what I get. It just means that `fut1` does not implement `Unpin`.

Comment: fn fn1() -> impl Future<Output=i32> + Unpin {async {}.boxed()} is ok, and then Pin::new() can works, this does not require Pin::new_unchecked(). but have other problem in myself reply , code to see post floor #2

Answer (score -3):

I have changed code to following, complie ok, but result incorrect: the async fn will be called by poll way in Future::poll(), but the .await statement in the async fn will be blocked forever.

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::{Arc,Mutex};
use futures::FutureExt;

#[pin_project::pin_project]
struct Person<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    age: i32,
}

impl<'a> Future for Person<'a> {
    type Output = i32;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let mut this = self.project();
        *this.age += 10;

        let mut fut1 = fn1();
        let pinfut1 =  Pin::new(&mut fut1);
        //let pinfut1 = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut fut1) };
        pinfut1.poll(cx)
    }
}

fn fn1() -> impl Future<Output=i32> + Unpin {
    async {
        dbg!("sleep start!"); // execute here!
        async_std::task::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(5)).await; //  <--- blocked here ?
        dbg!("sleep done!"); // Never execute here！
        123
    }.boxed()
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Person {name: "jack", age: Default::default()};
    async_std::task::block_on(async {
        let a = p1.await;
        dbg!(a); // Never execute here! // expect 123
    });
    std::thread::park();
}
```

Comment: What guarantees need to be made to ensure that this unsafe block is safe? Is it safe in general? Or is it only safe for this example?